# Get cell value with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to pass XML code to XSL

I have this code XML:

```
<cell colid="0" name="TIPO" status="FREJECT" value="SUPERMERCADO" page="0" left="254" top="1633" width="346" height="38" />
```

I need to take the value "SUPERMERCADO" from the cell on code xsl

Comment: Use `<xsl:value-of select="cell/@value" />`

Comment: and if I have another cell, for example the first cell has the attribute name = "TIPO" and the second cell has name = "CIUDAD", as a discriminator between them?

Comment: Use `<xsl:value-of select="cell[@name='TIPO']/@value" />` to get the first one distinctively.

Comment: and, 
to get the value that is between the middle of the field`<field id="CH_RUT" type="STGString">11.476.088-9</field>`... the value 11.476.088-9

Comment: Use `<xsl:value-of select="field[@id='CH_RUT']/text()" />` to get just the value of `field`.